# how to turn jquery object into usable html?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code alerts: "object Object"

```
var shipImgs = $("#div").children();
alert(shipImgs);
```

div contains 4 children (image tags).

```
<div id="div">
    <img src="/imgs/spaceship_still.jpg" alt="space"/>
    <img src="/imgs/spaceship_laser.jpg" alt="space"/>
    <img src="/imgs/spaceship_motion.jpg" alt="space"/>
    <img src="/imgs/spaceship_destroyed.jpg" alt="space"/>
</div>
```

I'd like each of these images to be added to an array. But before I can even do that, I need to know how to handle shipImgs... How can I access that object and get the html to push to the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the div has more than one children then `$("#div").children` will already return you an array

http://jsfiddle.net/jBVZU/

---

or do you want to get an array of `img` `src`??

```
var shipImgs = $("#div").children();
console.log(shipImgs);

var imgArr=[];

$.each(shipImgs,function(i,elem){
imgArr.push($(elem).attr("src"));
});
console.log(imgArr);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jBVZU/1/)

Comment: in simple terms, jQuery objects are just arrays with "decorative methods"

Comment: Thanks @3nigma, the second part was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will store the actual html string of the image in an array.

```
var imageArray = [],
shipImgs = $("#div").children();

shipImgs.each(function () {
    var imghtml = $(this);

    imageArray.push(imghtml.wrap('<div />').parent().html());
});
```